# Database engine alternatives for small C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have to develop a mini application, but need to create database, i did't want to use sql, access or oracle because i just need 4 tables data. What is the best option for database storage? Desktop application.

Comment: SQL Server CE is just a .DLL file (the engine) and the databases are .sdf files. mininum install. You could also store your data in an XML or even text file.

Comment: Why in the world don't you even want to use access?  It doesn't require access to be installed to use an access database in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo db is a very light weight, very easy no-sql database, which is rather easy to learn and work with.  It does require an instance running, I didn't check if you can have it embedded in your application but wouldn't be surprised if it's possible.

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need SP's and you only need relational data (and not dealing with installation and dependency overhead) then you just reference SQL Server CE.

It's an embedded database and if you run C# it means that the Framework is there, and probably the SQL Server CE too, otherwise the install is very lightweight and can be included in your installer

Comment: This is the way I'd go as well, for a small application.  However, the OP doesn't even want to use Access (for some reason) and that's even lighter weight than SQL CE.

Comment: SQL CE Tool? will you plz elaborate? i did't know about that.

Comment: @dodexahedron yes it's the best option for having simple but not so simple data storage. I would think access is a bit more complicated compared to SQLCE, remember access is a full ODBC complaint database, so there's an extra layer between your app and your database. SQL CE is just another DLL from your app.

Comment: @ghazanfarseyal Check the following links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134%28SQL.80%29.aspx     and this is the most interesting:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Comment: @Adrian Salazar thankyou so much. this is that i required.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite if you need relations and queries, ESENT if you don't.